# error installing wxWidgets on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, wxwidgets

I have ubuntu 14.04 running on my nvidia jetson Tk1 board and I am trying to install the wxWidgets toolkit onto it. So, my system configuration is:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
```

So, for my installation, I used the guidelines here: http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/WxWidgets30Binaries

I imported the key and added the repository as:

```
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.0.2/ubuntu/ trusty universe
```

Then I ran

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

However when i do that, I get the following at the end:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.0.2/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
Unable to find expected entry 'universe/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

Then when I try and install the wxWidgets packages, I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package libwxbase3.0-0-unofficial
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libwxbase3.0-0-unofficial'
E: Unable to locate package libwxgtk3.0-0-unofficial
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libwxgtk3.0-0-unofficial'
E: Unable to locate package libwxbase3.0-dbg
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libwxbase3.0-dbg'
E: Unable to locate package libwxgtk3.0-dbg
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libwxgtk3.0-dbg'
E: Package 'wx3.0-doc' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Well, to me it seems that in that repository there's no libwx for arm. Is it available in the default repositories?

Comment: Ahhhhh...that must be it! Building it from sources now. *fingers crossed*

Comment: @juzzlin That was the problem. Thank you! Do you want to write it as an answer, so I can give you credit?